# How to show check icon on selected card in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to show check icon on the selected card like this [image]

how I can achieve this ?
any idea or suggestion please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: By adding some kind of active class

Comment: Thanks @MayankPandeyz i am using on active class but there I am changing background color and don't know how to show icon any idea?

Comment: you can display:none icon and only make it visible when the card is active

Comment: Thanks @VoQuocThang i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
<div className="col" onClick={() => selectCard(2)}>
   <div className={isActiveCard === 2 ? "active-icon" : "d-none"}>
        <i className="bi bi-check-circle-fill text-appcolor"></i>
   </div>
   <div className={2 === isActiveCard ? "icon-card-active p-4 mx-auto icon-card" : "card p-4 mx-auto icon-card"}>
        <div className="text-center">
            <img src={shoesIcon} className="img-fluid main-icon" alt="logo" />
            <p className={2 === isActiveCard ? "icon-title-active" : "icon-title"}>Footwear</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```